# Filter Array of objects by specific key

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to filter through an array of objects (shown below) that when a user types in an input field, it returns what is searched. I would like to search specific by the `name` key and return the corresponding value.

*With what I currently have I keep getting the following error:*

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

**Initial State:**

```
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
```

**Array of Objects:**

```
const people = [
  { name: 'Siri', id: 'siri' },
  { name: 'Alexa', id: 'alexa' },
  { name: 'Google', id: 'google' },
  { name: 'Facebook', id: 'facebook' },
  { name: 'Twitter', id: 'twitter' },
  { name: 'LinkedIn', id: 'linkedin' },
];
```

**useEffect:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const searchResults = processorOptions.filter((o) =>
      Object.keys(o).some((k) => o[k].toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm))
    );

    setSearchResults(searchResults);
}, [searchTerm]);
```

**Search Field:**

```
<input
    name='peopleSearch'
    id='peopleSearch'
    className='form-control'
    type='text'
    placeholder='Filter by Name'
/>
```

**Displaying Search Results:**

```
{searchResults.map((item) => (
    <li>{item}</li>
))}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to display the name of the item instead of the item itself:

```
{searchResults.map((item) => (
    <li>{item.name}</li>
))}
```